# Apache 403 and @ on file permissions

Tags: macos, apache, permissions, filesystems, terminal

i have a (REALLY) simple website config on Apache2 (on a Mountain Lion Mac Os X) :

ServerName myServerName
    Directory /myDirectory/myWebsite

i graceful'd Apache and all i get is a 403.
Didn't work even after changing permissions 777 on all files and folders of my website.
But, when i "ls -l" the files, i get the following permissions :

(for directory)
drwxrwxrwx@

The only difference is the "@", but i can't find what it means (not sure it's properly processed when googled); can anyone please tell me what the "@" stands for ?

FYI, files are "real files", not aliases or symbolic links, and i have other websites running properly on the same server (but without the "@").

Thx

Comment: @DanielA.White **No, it doesn't.** This question has *nothing* to do with system administration: it is a basic Unix question that can be (and should have been) answered by reading the manual page for `ls` on the system in question. If you *must* migrate it somewhere it should have gone to [apple.se].

Comment: And more importantly, does the @ extended attributes block apache and if so, how to remove those extended attrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ means file has extended attributes. Display them using ls -l@. Read ls man page [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html)

Comment: can't believe i didn't think to man the ls command...thanks.

Comment: had com.apple.quarantine tagged, as well as com.macromates.caret on some files. Just use the xattr command (with -r for recursive, and -d com.macromates.caret for your tags).